# How to scrape from headings and content

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I've been given a pile of about 100 html files that I want to put into rectangular form. Here's an example: http://www.skeptron.uu.se/broady/arkiv/a/ffo/kapital/abergsson-anna.html . I would like to extract headings (h3) as column names and the content in between as strings taking up one row each.

I've managed to extract the column names with Rvest in R, but I'm stuck at extracting the content. I'm sure I'll get stuck again when trying to bind everything together in one dataframe.

This is what I've done for extracting the variable names:

```
variable.names <- map(LIST.html, ~read_html(.x) %>% 
                       html_nodes("h3") %>% 
                       html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
                       tolower())
```

Here's the code I used to get all the files: `system( "wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=3 -R index.html http://www.skeptron.uu.se/broady/arkiv/a/ffo/kapital/"  )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

malformed_documents <- character(0)

parse_profile_page <- function(pg, nm) {
  # extract section divs, omit byline
  divs <- html_nodes(pg, '#mittvagn > div')[ -1 ]
  idx <- which((lapply(divs, html_attr, 'id') |> unlist()) == 'bakvagn')
  if (length(idx) > 0) {
    divs <- divs[ -idx ]
  }
  # extract section headers
  titles <- html_nodes(divs, 'h3') |> 
    html_text(trim = TRUE) |> 
    tolower() |>
    unlist()
  # extract section contents
  paragraphs <- lapply(divs, html_nodes, 'p') |> 
    lapply(html_text, trim = TRUE) |> 
    lapply(paste0, collapse = '\n') |> 
    lapply(str_squish) |> 
    unlist()
  if (length(paragraphs) != length(titles)) {
    message(sprintf('%s is malformed, not parsing', nm))
    malformed_documents <<- c(malformed_documents, nm)
    return(data.frame())
  }
  df <- data.frame(title = titles, 
                   contents = paragraphs, 
                   url = rep(nm, length(paragraphs)))
  df
}

# obtain list of files to download
url <- 'http://www.skeptron.uu.se/broady/arkiv/a/ffo/kapital/'
pg <- read_html(url)
file_urls <- html_nodes(pg, '#mittvagn > ol > li > a:nth-child(1)') |> 
  html_attr('href') |> 
  str_replace_all('^\\.\\./', '') |> 
  sprintf(fmt= 'http://www.skeptron.uu.se/broady/arkiv/a/ffo/%s')
# file_urls <- sample(file_urls, 10) # uncomment to run on a small sample of pages

file_contents <- lapply(file_urls, function(x) {
  message('downloading: ', x)
  fl <- read_html(x)
})
names(file_contents) <- file_urls

parsed_contents <- lapply(file_urls, function(x) {
  message('parsing: ', x)
  pg <- file_contents[[ x ]]
  parse_profile_page(pg, x)
})
parsed_contents_df <- rbindlist(parsed_contents) |> as.data.frame()
if (length(malformed_documents) > 0) {
  warning('the following documents were malformed and not parsed: %s', paste0(malformed_documents, collapse = ', '))  
}
View(parsed_contents_df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I tried running the code, but when I get to line 34 I get `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.`. Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Line 34 onwards:

`file_contents <- lapply(file_urls, function(x) {
  message('downloading: ', x)
  fl <- read_html(x)
})`

Comment: Apologies there was a typo in my code. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks again! I've got one more issue. It now spits out an error when `parsed_contents_df`. Here it is: `Error in data.frame(title = titles, contents = paragraphs, url = rep(nm, : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 18, 19`

The problem seems to come from "kap-brummer-eugenie.htm".

Comment: I have added some error handling to skip over documents that are not formatted as the others are. I leave it as an exercise for you to deal with documents that deviate from the standard formatting.